# Sage CRM - Capture entity event update?

Tags: sage-crm

Can i alter/intercept the event when updating an entity?

For example, for when i update the company entity?

The idea is to delete somehting in the BBDD after the entity is updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Table Scripts to run functions when a record is inserted, after a record is inserted, when a record is updated, or when a record is deleted.

Table Scripts use JavaScript, but have access to the server-side functions (such as FindRecord, SQL statements, etc).

So, you can add a Table Script to the Entity to delete a record via a SQL statement when a record is updated.

It's difficult to give you an example without knowing exactly what you're trying to do though.

Six Ticks Support

Comment: Actually it is exactly what i did, the idea was to delete the relation to the workflow when a company entity was updated, so i use the table scripts like:

`function UpdateRecord(){
var entityID= new String(CRM.GetContextInfo("Company","Comp_CompanyId"));

var sql = "UPDATE vCompany SET Comp_WorkflowId = NULL WHERE Comp_CompanyId ="+entityID+";";
Query = CRM.CreateQueryObj(sql);
Query.ExecSQL();

}`

Comment: Perfect, although you could also consider adding a workflow state for "Closed" or something similar. You can then update the Workflow Instance for that record to set the workflow to "Closed" by default. Depending on what you're trying to do, it could be better practice to close a workflow rather than delete a link. Good job though!

Comment: cant use a Closed state because the transition rule is an .asp page that calls a .exe and for busniness logic, if the entity is updated the .exe has to be called again manually

Comment: can u help me with another issue? It is possible to create a select field in the Company entity that its options are, for example, products from the Product secondary entity? I thgout i would create a block list in the product entity? Create a list with the fields i want to show in the select? It is posible to do so? The idea is that the final user con select a product from a select/dropdown list

Comment: Nwm i think i just figured out :) In the Company entity create a new field with Advanced search  as input type and in the "Search entity" select "New product"

Comment: Using SQL to update the Worfklow Instance won't run the transition rule. So, if you need the asp page to run, do the SQL after the rule has actioned. If you want to stop the asp page running, do the update before the transition rule has actioned. That way, you can still use the Workflow and set the state to closed, but you have the option of either running or ignoring the asp page.

Comment: You can also do Advanced Search Select for any entity (even custom entities) by adding some translations. Check out this article by Jeff Richards:
https://community.sagecrm.com/partner_community/b/hints_tips_and_tricks/archive/2007/06/23/how-do-i-add-the-id-from-a-custom-table-table-as-an-search-select-advanced.aspx

Comment: Ty for your answer will try that